# UIScrollView zoomed won't produce swipe

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with zooming enabled, and a swipe gesture recognizer setup.  When the user is not zoomed, the swipes come through great, but as soon as the user zooms in, the swipe won't come through.

My swipe recognizer is applied to the imageview, and I have tried to apply it to the scroller also.  When zoomed, no go.

Is there a secret to getting the swipe while zoomed?

Thanks in advance!

Rob

Comment: Sounds like the swipe is not recognising because it's not crossing the minimum distance once zoomed up. You'd need to correct the touch points being sent to the recogniser for the zoom level, or make your own recogniser.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your swipe gesture recognizer?

Have you tried setting `scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a secret to getting the swipe
>   while zoomed?

Yes, there is. Each UIImageView should be inside its own UIScrollView which in turn are inside of main UIScrollView. No gesture recognizers are needed, just set UIScrollViews options like zoom scales etc and implement UIScrollViewDelegate methods for master UIScrollView.